# Python - How to dynamically create separate tuple lists out of a single tuple list

Tags: python

I would like to create a dynamic tuple list from the tuple list below:

`Optimal_Route = [(1, 5), (2, 3), (3, 1), (4, 2), (5, 4)]`.

My end goal is to have something such as below:

Route = [[(1, 5), (5, 4), (4, 2)], [(2, 3), (3, 1)]]

I would like this "Route" tuple list of lists to be dynamic based on the "depotList" and "affectedAreaList". Below is the piece of code I wrote for this task, but I am struggling to make it efficient and dynamic. I would kindly some help with this. Thanks

```
Optimal_Route = [(1, 5), (2, 3), (3, 1), (4, 2), (5, 4)]
Route = []
depotList = [1,2]
affectedAreaList = [3,4,5]
count = 0
while count < len(Optimal_Route):
    next_route = True
    cur_route = []
    for tup in Optimal_Route:
        if tup[0] in depotList and next_route == True:   
            cur_route.append(tup)
            b = tup[1]
            for tup in Optimal_Route:
                if tup[0] == b:
                    cur_route.append(tup)
                    if not tup[1] in depotList:
                        next_route = False
                        b = tup[1]
                        print b
                        for tup in Optimal_Route:
                            if tup[0] == b:
                                cur_route.append(tup)

            Route.append(cur_route)
            next_route = True
            cur_route = []
        count +=1
```

Comment: I don't understand the logic behind it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the basis of the data you provide, use a dictionary rather than processing the tuples :

```
Optimal_Route = [(1, 5), (2, 3), (3, 1), (4, 2), (5, 4)]
Route = []
depotList = [1,2]
affectedAreaList = [3,4,5]

legs = dict(Optimal_Route)
routes = {}
for start in depotList :
    place = start
    routes[start] = []
    end_places = [ i for i in depotList if i != start ]
    while place not in end_places :
        routes[start].append((place,legs[place]))
        place = legs[place]

for i in routes.keys() :
    print(i,routes[i])

print([ i for i in routes.values()])
```

Comment: Thanks, Bill! But as the "Optimal_Route" list increases in length, say this one; [(1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5), (3, 1), (3, 2), (4, 1), (4, 2), (5, 1), (5, 2)], I get this error - "routes[start].append((place,legs[place])):MemoryError"- same as my original code. Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Well I did say your original data, what you have done is complicate the data as now there are more than one route from an affectedArea, for example how do we choose between (5,1) or (5,2) ?. Can you provide a rule ?.